# nfs server on linux with windows 10 client

Tags: nfs, windows-10, raspbian

I have a nfs server on a raspberry pi 3 b+, that share an ext4 directory.
The nfs client is a windows 10 computer.

I have a problem with filename characters encoding on client side. All accent characters are displayed badly (I am a french speaker, so some words have character like 'é' or 'è' for example).

My local setting on server side was en_US.UTF-8. I have changed it to fr_FR.UTF-8 but it change nothing.
It seems that nfs version used is nfs v3. But I didn't manage to force it to v4.
I have tried with a share directory on a ntfs partition, it's work fine and all wharacter well displayed.

Do you know what is the root cause of this type of problem ?

Comment: Do you mean characters in the file names, or characters in the files themselves?

Comment: I mean characters in the filename

Answer (score 3):

There is no nfs4 client for windows. You better try to use samba for windows clients, but keep nfs export  for unix hosts in parallel.

Comment: Upvoted. Highest currently supported nfs client is nfs3

Comment: @TimothyFrew Linux, FreeBSD have 4.2 clients. Solaris support v4.1,  OSX (with some long outstanding bugs) 4.0. Windows is the only OS that supports only v2 and v3, though they have nfsv4.1 server.

Comment: Yes I agree with you

Comment: Seriously? I have been wasting 2 weeks trying all the combinations and permutations from windows to connect to a nfs4 server and it was that windows simply can't?! And is there any user-space client for v4?